Analog data operations do not work in PIC12F675, there is not even a reaction on GPIO pins
This Analog data is read and the number 1-5 is shown on the 7 segment common anode display with 7447, but I can't set this number for analog value because I can't show analog values or output I wrote this code in MPLAB X IDE.
#include <xc.h>

#pragma config FOSC = INTRCIO   // Oscillator Selection bits (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on GP4/OSC2/CLKOUT pin, I/O function on GP5/OSC1/CLKIN)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-Up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // GP3/MCLR pin function select (GP3/MCLR pin function is MCLR)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Detect Enable bit (BOD disabled)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code Protection bit (Program Memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF   

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
#define HIGH 1
#define LOW 0

unsigned int adc_value=0;

void main(void) {
    TRISIObits.TRISIO0 = 1;
    TRISIObits.TRISIO1 = 0;
    TRISIObits.TRISIO2 = 0;
    TRISIObits.TRISIO4 = 0;
    TRISIObits.TRISIO5 = 0;
    
    ANSELbits.ADCS2 = 0;
    ANSELbits.ADCS1 = 0;
    ANSELbits.ADCS0 = 0;
    ANSELbits.ANS0 = 1;
    
    ADCON0bits.CHS0 = 0;
    ADCON0bits.CHS1 = 0;
    ADCON0bits.ADON = 1;
    ADCON0bits.GO = 1;
    ADCON0bits.ADFM = 1;

    while(1) {
        ADON = 1;
        GO_DONE = 1;
        while(GO_DONE);
        adc_value = (((unsigned int) ADRESH << 8) + ADRESL);
        ADON = 0;
        if (adc_value >= 0 && adc_value <= 200) {
            GP4 = 0;
            GP5 = 0;
            GP2 = 0;
            GP1 = 0;
        } else if (adc_value > 200 && adc_value <= 400) {
            GP4 = 0;
            GP5 = 0;
            GP2 = 0;
            GP1 = 1;
        } else if (adc_value > 400 && adc_value <= 600) {
            TRISIObits.TRISIO4 = 0;
            TRISIObits.TRISIO5 = 0;
            TRISIObits.TRISIO2 = 1;
            TRISIObits.TRISIO1 = 0;
        } else if (adc_value > 600 && adc_value <= 800) {
            TRISIObits.TRISIO4 = 0;
            TRISIObits.TRISIO5 = 0;
            TRISIObits.TRISIO2 = 1;
            TRISIObits.TRISIO1 = 1;
        } else if (adc_value > 800 && adc_value <= 1023) {
            TRISIObits.TRISIO4 = 0;
            TRISIObits.TRISIO5 = 1;
            TRISIObits.TRISIO2 = 0;
            TRISIObits.TRISIO1 = 0;
        } else {
            TRISIObits.TRISIO4 = 1;
            TRISIObits.TRISIO5 = 1;
            TRISIObits.TRISIO2 = 1;
            TRISIObits.TRISIO1 = 1;
        }
        __delay_ms(100);
    }
    return;
}

my aim in this project is to print the number between 0-5 on the 7 segment common anode display according to the analog data between 0-1023, but I could not solve this problem.


You state that analog operations do not work. How did you verify that your problem is not the GPIO part dealing with the LEDs? Did you do any debugging? Do you ever get beyond that line while(GO_DONE);? Assuming GO_DONE is some hardware flag that changes at some point in time. If you replace adcres by a simple counter, does the display change correctly?

I don't know that micro, but using different methods (GP4 = 0; vs TRISIObits.TRISIO4 = 0;)  to access the pins of your U2 chip, looks very strange.

“while(GO_DONE);” Even when I remove this line, the situation is the same, I added and removed it, I tried a lot of functions, the situation is the same

@Gerhardh I tried it to see which method would activate those pins.

That means you do not know if you can access the pins? So, you do not know if you have a problem with reading analog data or with setting the pins, correct? Then again, what happens if you remove while(GO_DONE) and just count up adc_value. Do not try to solve 2 different task at the same time. First make sure you have your display under control before you try to read the values.

@Gerhard I can access the pins now, but it does not give the correct number, no matter what I do, it gives the numbers 6 and 7.

As a solution, according to the code given by @Kozmotronik, the problem was solved when 74hc595 was used instead of 7447.
This is the solved code and scheme:

#include <xc.h>

#pragma config FOSC = INTRCIO   // Internal oscillator
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer disabled
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer disabled
#pragma config MCLRE = ON      // GP3/MCLR pin function is digital I/O
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset enabled
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code Protection disabled
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data Memory Code Protection disabled

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

#define ST_CP GP4
#define DS GP2
#define SH_CP GP1


unsigned int adc_value = 0;
float volt=0;
uint8_t LED [10]={
  0xE7, //0    0xE7
  0x21, //1
  0xDB, //2   0xD3
  0x6B, //3   0xD6
  0x3D, // 4  0xB4
  0x7E, // 5  0x76
  0xEE, //6
  0x23, //7   0xE4
  0xEF, //8
  0x7F, //9   0xF6
};

void spi_shift_out(uint8_t data) {
    uint8_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (data & (1 << (7 - i))) {
            DS = 1;
        } else {
            DS = 0;
        }
        
        SH_CP = 1;
        __delay_us(1);
        SH_CP = 0;
    }
    
    ST_CP = 1;
    __delay_us(1);
    ST_CP = 0; 
}

void display_digit(uint8_t digit) {
    spi_shift_out(LED[digit]);
}

void main(void) {
    GPIO = 0; // Clear output latches
    CMCON = 7; // Turn off analog comparators
    TRISIO = 1; // GP0 and GP3 (GP3 is an only input pin) are input and other pins are output
    ANSEL = 0x21; 
    ADCON0 = 0x81; 
    while (1) {
        ADCON0bits.GO = 1;
        while (ADCON0bits.GO);
        adc_value = (ADRESH <<8) + ADRESL;
        volt=(adc_value*5)/1023;
        if (volt >= 0 && adc_value < 0.99) {
            display_digit(0);
        } else if (volt >= 1.0 && volt < 1.99) {
            display_digit(1);
        } else if (volt >= 2.0 && volt < 2.99) {
            display_digit(2);
        } else if (volt >= 3.0 && volt < 3.99) {
            display_digit(3);
        } else if (volt >= 4.0 && volt <= 4.99) {
            display_digit(4);
        } else {
            display_digit(4);
        }
        __delay_ms(100);
    }

    return;
}



Could you please explain your answer?

Where is any hint about using some other hardware hidden in that code or the whole answer?

You haven't configured GPIO<1:5> as digital IOs. That's why you cannot control them.
According to the device's datasheet you muxt configure them using the CMCON and the ANSEL register.
Turn off the analog comparators
The CMCON register controls the built in analog comparators that uses several pins that connect the internal hardware to the outside world via the GP0 (CIN+), GP1 (CIN-) and GP2 (COUT) pins respectively. So you need to turn off the comparators hardware first by setting the CM2:CM0 bits to 7 (111 in binary).
CMCON = 7;

Configure analog and digital outputs
The ANSEL register is where you can tell the micro what pins you wanna use for ADC operation. In your case, since you use only the AN0 (GP0) and the rest must be configured as digital. What you wanna do is to set the corresponding ANSx bit for the pin you wanna use as analog input (you use AN0 hence you must set ANS0), and the rest of the ANSx bits must be set to 0 to use other pins as digital IO.
ANSEL = 1;

Let's tidy up your code
So if we wrap up the information above and merge it into your code, and also tidy up your code, the final code should look like this:
#include <xc.h>

#pragma config FOSC = INTRCIO   // Oscillator Selection bits (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on GP4/OSC2/CLKOUT pin, I/O function on GP5/OSC1/CLKIN)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-Up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // GP3/MCLR pin function select (GP3/MCLR pin function is MCLR)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Detect Enable bit (BOD disabled)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code Protection bit (Program Memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
#define HIGH 1
#define LOW 0


void setupInputs() {
    GPIO = 0; // Clear output latches
    CMCON = 7; // Turn off analog comparators
    TRISIO = 1; // GP0 and GP3 (GP3 is an only input pin) are input and other pins are output
}

void setupADC() {
    ANSEL = 0x21; // Set the GP0 pin as analog input and the rest is digital IO
                  // and use the internal RC osc for ADC
    ADCON0 = 0x81; // Right justify, sample CH0, ADC turn on
}

unsigned int getAnalogValueOnCh0() {
    ADCON0bits.GO = 1;
    while(ADCON0bits.GO)
        ;                // Wait for the ADC conversion to complete
    return (unsigned int) ( ADRESH << 8) + ADRESL;
}

void setDisplay(char value) {
    GP1 = value & 1;
    GP2 = (value & 2) >> 1;
    GP4 = (value & 4) >> 2;
    GP5 = (value & 8) >> 3;
}

void main(void) {

    setupInputs();
    setupADC();
    setDisplay(0);
    __delay_us(20); // See datasheet 7.2 A/D ACquisition Requirements

    while(1) {
        unsigned int adc_value = getAnalogValueOnCh0();
        if (adc_value >= 0 && adc_value <= 200) {
            setDisplay(0);
        } else if (adc_value > 200 && adc_value <= 400) {
            setDisplay(1);
        } else if (adc_value > 400 && adc_value <= 600) {
            setDisplay(2);
        } else if (adc_value > 600 && adc_value <= 800) {
            setDisplay(3);
        } else if (adc_value > 800 && adc_value <= 1023) {
            setDisplay(4);
        } else {
            setDisplay(5);
        }
        __delay_ms(100);
    }
}

PS: You shoud have ranged the values in 1024 / 6 = 170 approx. But you sliced the ADC valur into the chunks of 200. You choose.

In the solution, when MCLRE is OFF, it shows 0 and 1 volt correctly, but 2,3,4,5 does not output, when MCLRE is ON, it does not output from the pins. ) –
CrazyProgrammer
Commented12 mins ago

When I activated the MCLRE pin and connected it to the plus line with 10K, the same situation occurred again.

The problem was in the setDisplay function. I fixed it check it out.
